# What does this notation $p(s', r \mid s, a)$ mean in reinforcement learning?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, reinforcement-learning, notation

I was reading a book on reinforcement learning, and came across the following notation:

[image]

Possibly rather basic question, but I cant seem to google how to read this. Is it

A) Probability of (s' and r) GIVEN (s and a)

B) Probability of s' and (r GIVEN s) and a?

I really could not find any guide on how to read this triple notation online. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is A.

It is the probability that the state ($S_t$) **and** reward ($R_t$) at time $t$ are respectively equal to *some* $s'$ and $r$, given that the state ($S_{t-1}$) **and** the action taken from that state ($A_{t-1}$) at time $t-1$ are respectively equal to *some* $s$ and $a$.

In other words, this is a "joint" probability where you are conditioning on more than one variable.